# Is it acceptable to write "(wo)man"?

Tags: grammatical-gender

I just read this: [It’s a (wo)man’s world out there](http://www.liverpoolecho.co.uk/property/property-news/2011/01/14/it-s-a-wo-man-s-world-out-there-100252-27987921/).

Is this an accepted approach to gender-neutral language, or is it just used when humor is intended?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The style guides I know advise against this kind, with the brackets or slashes (he/she), unless used ironically or in contexts where there is no reasonable alternative to avoid confusion, like forms or legal texts.

Comment: @Cerberus: Sorry, out of upvotes for the next 22 hours!

Comment: @Jimi: Haha, have you really reached the cap? Pretty impressive.

Comment: @Cerberus: You bet! Have to do my civic duty, you know ;)

Comment: It's bad enough in English, but when you move to a language where you have to accord all the rest, it starts looking more like code than prose :)

Comment: @Cerberus: last night I hit the 30 vote daily cap too... for the first time on any \*.SE site (including the trilogy).  Hmm, wasn't *that* hard. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, this would be even worse in a legal text.

Answer (score 7):

This is certainly not an attempt at gender-neutrality. It is simply employed to convey the irony of the situation in question.

Comment: I've known this construct used for gender neutrality a lot.  In that specific example, it is done for effect.

Comment: @Orbling: Oh, yeah, for sure. I was referring specifically to the article the asker posted. Like you said, it's used here for effect... I wouldn't hesitate at constructions such as this or *s/he* or even *(fe)male* and the like :)

Comment: Good, was not entirely sure from the phrasing - but figured that was your intention. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: No worries :) Yeah, this was a very quick answer...